# Using variables in awk command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to find the UID in a certain range and only showing those UIDs with their name.
The range is determined by two arguments I enter in my command line.
However, I don't receive the right answer in the code I am using now.
Below, the first command shows running the code I am using now. In the second command, you will see the answer that I *should* have.

```bash
$ ./UserID 10 100
root:0
$ ./UserID 10 100
operator: 11
games: 12
ftp: 14
dbus: 81
apache: 48
tss:59
avahi: 70
грс:32
rpcuser: 29
gdm: 42
sshd: 74
tcpdump: 72
```

```bash
#! /bin/bash

min=$1
max=$2

awk -F: '($3>=min) && ($3<=max ) {printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: You haven't actually used the `min` or `max` variables anywhere after defining them.

Comment: Your problem description "*I don't recieve the right answer*" is not clear. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste some example input and the actual output you get and show the expected output.

Comment: Does the stackoverflow question ["How do I use shell variables in an awk script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) solve your problem?

Comment: `awk` cannot see shell variables -- they use different name spaces. Pass the shell values into awk like: `awk -v min="${min}" -v max="${max}" -F: ....`. Your image clips off the command -- I assume you are reading /etc/passwd. Don't post images -- please add the data or code as a code block.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

min=$1
max=$2

awk -F: -v min="$min" -v max="$max" '($3>=min) && ($3<=max) {printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: If `min` and `max` are not used elsewhere, then `-v min="$1"` etc is perfectly good too.